# Differentiate 2 GET Request with Express and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

Is there a way to differentiate 2 GET Requests with exactly the same "format" like :

```
app.get("/user/:id", function(req,res){
    ...
});
app.get("/user/:name", function(req,res){
   ...
});
```

Comment: Those are essentially the same, just with different named parameters. There's no way to differentiate.